# Web services not running in android project?

Tags: android, web-services, json

I am accessing the JSON webServices but it is not running and it is showing execption.

I made a activity and calling the services from this activity class, when i run from java code services running fine but not running in android....what could be the reason behind this?

I am following standard code of calling from another project, also the services running in that project but not on mine. thanks.

Comment: please update your code and more elaboration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add permissions to access internet before calling services,

add following lines to your menifest files.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
```

check and tell if still there any problem